# Restart network interface after reconfiguration of default gateway

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, headless

I had to swap out my router, and unfortunately that also means changing the default gateway.

I have updated the configuration in `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yml` with my net configuration and run `# ip link set eno1 down && ip link set eno1 up`, which corresponds with my network adapter:

> ```
> 2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
>     link/ether 68:1d:ef:29:94:99 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>     altname enp1s0
>     inet 10.18.10.242/24 brd 10.18.10.255 scope global eno1
>        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
>     inet6 fe80::6a1d:efff:fe29:9499/64 scope link
>        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
> ```

I expected this to work, since executing `# ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0` worked on my debian box after updating `/etc/network/interfaces`. I  could `ping 1.1.1.1` with success.

I have tried all of the following (after executing `sudo -i`) with a "*No such file or directory*", "*Command 'XXXX' not found, but can be installed with: ...*" or similar error:

- `/etc/init.d/network restart`
- `systemctl restart network`
- `systemctl restart NetworkManager`
- `nmcli networking off && nmcli networking on`
- `service network-manager restart`
- `systemctl restart NetworkManager.service`

What can I do besides restarting the box (which I do not want to do, if possible)

I know I can `apt install ifupdown`or `apt install ifupdow-ng` but I assume that the reason for not having these installed per default is that there is a newer, smarter way to do this, which eludes me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try just renewing the DHCP IP address instead of downing the card and bringing it back up.

```sh
sudo dhclient -r -v eno1 && sudo dhclient -v eno1
```

But, if you are to down the NIC and bring it back up make sure that you are using `sudo` with your command to elevate it

```sh
sudo ip link set eno1 down && sudo ip link set eno1 up
```

But, when I just tested that command, I still had to release and renew my IP address for it to come back up correctly.

Comment: as I wrote - I was in an escalated prompt (`sudo-i`) but running `ip link set eno1 down && ip link set eno1 up`  apparently worked this time

Comment: @JonasStumphStevnsvig "I have tried all of the following (after executing sudo -i)" is listed after the command in your question so I assumed that you only used it on the rest listed but not the first command. One issue with that command `sudo -i` is that it switches to root and may change the path and that is why you were getting command not found.  I always recommend that you use `sudo command` that way the path is always the same. But that is now moot since you did solve your issue.  Glad it is working for you!

Comment: I could have written "I have run all these with root privileges" which could indicate any of three methods. I am getting the command not found because many of the packages are not installed out of the box...